# How to update the Select ID of the entity in NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have the code below and I want to update the selectedScenarioID each time the user selects one of the entities the property is updated in the ngrx store.

```
export interface IScenarioState extends EntityState<ScenarioState> {
  selectedScenarioId: string | number | null;
}

export const initialState: IScenarioState = fromAdapter.adapter.getInitialState({
  selectedScenarioId: '00001'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NgRx Example App](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/books.reducer.ts#L69-L72), we have the exact same use case.

In short, you dispatch an action and you mutate state in the reducer.

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ViewBookPageActions.selectBook, (state, { id }) => ({
    ...state,
    selectedBookId: id,
  }))
);
```